# how I should send data from xib to viewcontroller?

Tags: swift, view, xib, pass-data

i have a view that is a xib, this view contains a buttons for a calculator, I did this because I need a custom keyboard for my app, my app has some views that needs this keyboard
the problem is, how I send the data from view to my view controller?
in my view controller I only has a textfield and a view with xib custom class

I use swift 4.2

[custom view and textflied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCP5r.png)

this is my code from my xib

```
import UIKit

class keyboardView: UIView {


@IBOutlet var viewKeyboard: UIView!

var textIntroduced = ""

override init(frame: CGRect) { // for using CustomView in code
    super.init(frame: frame)
    custom()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    custom()
}

private func custom()
{
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("keyboard", owner: self, options: nil)

    viewKeyboard.frame = self.bounds
    viewKeyboard.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight,.flexibleWidth]
    for view in viewKeyboard.subviews
    {
        view.isExclusiveTouch = true
    }
    addSubview(viewKeyboard)
}

@IBAction func addOne(_ sender: Any) {
    textIntroduced += "1"
}
@IBAction func addTwo(_ sender: Any) {
    textIntroduced += "2"
}
@IBAction func addThree(_ sender: Any) {
    textIntroduced += "3"
}
@IBAction func addFour(_ sender: Any) {
    textIntroduced += "4"
}
@IBAction func addFive(_ sender: Any) {
    textIntroduced += "5"
}
@IBAction func addSix(_ sender: Any) {
    textIntroduced += "6"
}
@IBAction func addSeven(_ sender: Any) {
    textIntroduced += "7"
}
@IBAction func addEight(_ sender: Any) {
    textIntroduced += "8"
}
@IBAction func addNine(_ sender: Any) {
    textIntroduced += "9"
}
@IBAction func addZero(_ sender: Any) {
    textIntroduced += "0"
    print(textIntroduced)
}
@IBAction func removeNumber(_ sender: Any) {
    textIntroduced.removeLast()
}
}
```

in my view controller I only has a textfield and view with custom class

i want to push any button view and the result should be written in the textfield.

Comment: Use an observer pattern, so the view controller and listen for changes from the view

Comment: Create a UIView object on the view controller through the IB.  Make an IBOutlet connection.  Change the class name of the view object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use protocol to observe data changes in your xib. First of all you need to create a protocol like this.

```
protocol NumberCalculable: class {
    func addNumber(_ number: Int)
}
```

Then, inside your xib file below your `viewKeyboard` outlet you need to create a delegate for your protocol.

```
weak var delegate: NumberCalculable?
```

Instead of doing `textIntroduced += 1` you should change with this `delegate?.addNumber(1)` and same for other `IBAction` methods.
Thirdly, you need to conform your protocol in your `viewController` class doing 
`keyboardView.delegate = self` inside `viewDidLoad()` method.

```
extension ViewController: NumberCalculable {
func addNumber(_ number: Int) {
// do whatever you want
}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: great my friend, I've been trying this but without success, your solution has help me, thanks so much